# Drools 7.7.0 Installation Error

Tags: eclipse, drools

I am trying to install drools plugin into eclipse 4.2 (juno).
I have used this update site:

https://download.jboss.org/drools/release/7.7.0.Final/org.drools.updatesite/

Its throwing this error in the first step of installation:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: JBoss Drools Core Developer Resources 7.7.0.Final (org.drools.eclipse.feature.source.feature.group 7.7.0.Final)
  Missing requirement: JBoss Drools Core 7.7.0.Final (org.drools.eclipse.feature.feature.group 7.7.0.Final) requires 'org.eclipse.jgit 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: JBoss Drools Core Developer Resources 7.7.0.Final (org.drools.eclipse.feature.source.feature.group 7.7.0.Final)
    To: org.drools.eclipse.feature.feature.group [7.7.0.Final]
```

Please assist in resolving this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you have to install dependency then restart eclipse then install Jboss Drools. It will work.